# System.ArgumentNullException when GetDbContext in constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate, provider-model

I'm trying to use Entity Framework Core with ASP.NET Boilerplate .NET Core, but I don't want to use Repository built-in functions.

There is a problem with my DB context; it keeps returning:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'

for the `DbContext` instance as shown below:

```
public class MainProjectsAppService : ApplicationService
{
    private readonly DecentralizationDbContext _ctx;

    public MainProjectsAppService(IDbContextProvider<DecentralizationDbContext> dbContextProvider)
    {
        _ctx = dbContextProvider.GetDbContext();
    }

    public void CustomizedCreateMainProject(MainProject mainProject)
    {
        MainProject customizedMainProject = new MainProject
        {
            ...
        };

        _ctx.MainProjects.Add(customizedMainProject);
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

[image: My code screen shoot]

Below is the `DbContext` class code:

```
namespace Decentralization.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public class DecentralizationDbContext : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User, DecentralizationDbContext>
    {
        /* Define a DbSet for each entity of the application */

        public DbSet<MainProject> MainProjects { get; set; }
        public DecentralizationDbContext(DbContextOptions<DecentralizationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not call `dbContextProvider.GetDbContext()` in the constructor.

Define a getter instead:

```cs
public class MainProjectsAppService : ApplicationService
{
    private readonly IDbContextProvider<DecentralizationDbContext> _dbContextProvider;
    private DecentralizationDbContext _ctx => _dbContextProvider.GetDbContext();

    public MainProjectsAppService(IDbContextProvider<DecentralizationDbContext> dbContextProvider)
    {
        _dbContextProvider = dbContextProvider;
    }
}
```

Reference: [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#4809](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/4809)